# migrating from direct db access to ontology - does it make sense?

Tags: database, database-design, ontology, owl

- I have seen people working on an ontology. Few benefits, I know, about ontology is re-use and integrating
  multiple system i.e If we have
  several DB’s and we want to integrate
  them with each other, you will get
  many problems, because of their
  different formats. This problem has
  been solved by storing them in
  ontology.

  - We have many system that is based on RDBMS. So to make system intelligent (adding semantics), ontology driven system is used i.e migrating from Db to ontology.
  - But for this purpose, We have to re-design system (making ontology according to system specifications). **Instead of re-inventing the wheel, can't I make minor changes in Db that may make system intelligent.**
  - Lets say I have three systems A,B & C that is based on RDBMS. I cant integrate them but using ontology. For that I have to make ontology for each. **Instead of designing ontology, why shouldn't I go for designing Db (keep in mind three system).**

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to think about [D2R](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/d2r-server/).

Comment: Db to Rdf will returns me rdf. But I have heard that Data only in RDF is nothing more than another way of storing information. RDF is just a data-model. But do not have semantic in it. Hence using ontology adding axiom/semantic in it

Comment: I know but i think solving problems step by step would be easier. First map your DB to RDF. Then read rdf with a tool like [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/)  And after, it is up to you..

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to get ur point. what u trying to say is to retrieve data from RDF using Jena and then store it in ontology (.owl file).. M I correct ?

Comment: Yes, map you DB to RDF. Create an ontology with your RDF in jena. Do anything you want with your ontology.